# grpc k8s listen giving "too many colons"

Tags: kubernetes, grpc

In my Go GRPC Server, I am calling net.Listen("tcp", "9901") and I get the following error running in k8s:
level=fatal msg="Listen Failed: listen tcp: address tcp://10.101.156.95:9901: too many colons in address

I am not sure how the address is being filled in other than k8s magic. It is the loadbalancer IP for the pod though.

I can not figure where the too many colons are coming from.

Comment: For other viewers, In my case, I should have removed the `https://` from my URL

Answer (score 1):

When using in k8s the address/port should be left "", not the port you would use if running standalone.  Doing that solved that problem.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I don't understand what is the solution from this comment, could you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using https://github.com/sercand/kuberesolver and I faced the same error when I forgot to call `kuberesolver.RegisterInCluster()`. Spent some time to figure it out, not a very obvious error.